# How to get the current time/timestamp in smartpy contract?

Tags: smartpy

I deployed a smartpy contract in florencenet via smartpy.io. The command sp.timestamp_from_utc_now() used inside the program seems to be not giving the current time. Instead it is giving the same time the contract is deployed. How do I get the current time/timestamp in smartpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp.timestamp_from_utc_now()` is a helper function that only works at compilation time, meaning that it produces a constant and doesn't update at runtime.

*`timestamp_from_utc_now()` should be moved to `sp.utils` soon, which should avoid confusion*.

You want to use the instruction [sp.now](https://smartpy.io/reference.html#_timestamps) which gives the current block timestamp.

Comment: thanks a lot, @Rodrigo Quelhas. Your suggestion worked as per my requirement.